# Swift: Date string only has month and year, can I still produce a date?

Tags: swift, date

I'm porting some old Javascript code to a Swift app, my data-set from my client is a little strange in that they recorded just the month and year of each date, so an installation date string would look like: `2001-05`.

In Javascript I can use: `var date = new Date("2001-05");` to which it returns: `2001-05-01T00:00:00.000Z` zeroing the time/day but maintaining the year and month as expected.

I currently use the below code in Swift:

```
var date = "2001-05"

func stringToDate(_ date: String) -> Date? {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"

    return df.date(from: date)
}

print(stringToDate(date))
```

This always produces a nil output.  Is it possible to reproduce the JS behaviour of date-formatting in Swift?

Comment: Reasoning behind a downvote is always apprecaited...bit rude to downvote without justification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it, I tested it on playgrounds use it like this(Just changed the "yyyy-MM" part):

```
var date = "2001-05"

func stringToDate(_ date: String) -> Date? {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM"
    df.date(from: date)

    return df.date(from: date)
}

print(stringToDate(date)!)
```

Comment: Doh! Now I'm feeling dumb. I thought that format was the desired output format not the matching input format.   Thanks :)

Comment: No problem :D it happens to all of us sometimes! Please mark it as answered!

Comment: Simpler: `df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`. – And `df.date(from: date)` is needed only once.